# MySQLi extension is missing

Tags: apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

I see this message when go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
MySQLi is commented out in php.ini (php7.0 is used by apache)
Command 'php -m' in terminal shows that mysqli is installed, so why it is missing?
I suppose that maybe phpmyadmin use another phpversion instead of php7.0, is it possible?

Comment: Did you run `phpenmod mysqli`? `php -m` shows you all modules, including disabled.